# Consuming Rest Webservices in Oracle Jet

Tags: javascript, rest, web-services, oracle-jet

I am new in Oracle Jet. What I want to achieve, is to Consuming Rest Webservices in Oracle Jet Table.

That is my ViewModel

```
 function CustomerViewModel() {
     var self = this;

    self.DeptCol = ko.observable();
    self.datasource = ko.observable();

    self.serviceURL = '/hr/employees/';
    self.parseDept = function(response) {
        return {empno: response['empno'],
            DepartmentName: response['ename'],
            LocationId: response['job'],
            ManagerId: response['hiredate'],
            mgr: response['mgr'],
            sal: response['sal'],
            comm: response['comm'],
            deptno: response['deptno']};
    };
    self.Department = oj.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: self.serviceURL,
        parse: self.parseDept,
        idAttribute: 'empno'
    });

    self.myDept = new self.Department();
    self.DeptCollection = oj.Collection.extend({
        url: self.serviceURL,
        model: self.myDept
    });

    self.DeptCol(new self.DeptCollection());
}
```

That is my View

```
<table id="table" summary="Department List" aria-label="Departments Table" 
       data-bind="ojComponent:{  
   component:'ojTable',
   data:datasource,
   columns:[  
      {  
         headerText:'empno',
         field:'empno'
      },
      {  
         headerText:'ename',
         field:'DepartmentName'
      },
      {  
         headerText:'job',
         field:'LocationId'
      },
      {  
         headerText:'hiredate',
         field:'ManagerId'
      },
      {  
         headerText:'mgr',
         field:'mgr'
      },
      {  
         headerText:'sal',
         field:'sal'
      },
      {  
         headerText:'comm',
         field:'comm'
      },
      {  
         headerText:'deptno',
         field:'deptno'
      }
   ]
}"> 
</table>
```

When I test my Page, it doesn't show any Errors and the Page is blank. Somebody can help, please?
Thanks

Comment: Sometimes this happens because the data is being parsed incorrectly. Could you show the webservice response as well?

Comment: I don't see how you put the data into `datasource`. One line might be missing,

Comment: whether your problem got solved??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following tutorial [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/webclient/ojet-rest.html).
its having 2 scenarios :

1. Standard Jquery.
2. Oracle Jet Common model.

In the example that you provided you are using the Oracle jet Common model, which is very good for CRUD operation over Rest webservice.

I advice you also to take alook at the Standard Jquery scenario which is very helpful and easy to use.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your `CustomerViewModel` you probably miss actually setting the `datasource` observable:

```
self.datasource(new oj.CollectionTableDataSource(self.DeptCol()));
```